# Create Source from a polling method in Akka

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a method which gets elements from different sources using the poll method if there is a request for a new element. How can I create source from this method so that it only asks for a new element from polling method only?

Comment: You can have a look at https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-customize.html#using-timers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating with polling APIs is explained in the akka.io blog post: [Writing Akka Streams Connectors for existing APIs](https://akka.io/blog/2016/08/29/connecting-existing-apis) in the part "Polling based APIs".

At the core of it you'll want to extend a `TimerGraphStageLogic`, and do things like:

```
private void schedulePoll() {
  scheduleOnce("poll", pollInterval);
}

@Override
public void onTimer(Object timerKey) {
  if (!isClosed(out)) {
    doPoll();
    if (!buffer.isEmpty()) {
      pushHead();
    } else {
      schedulePoll();
    }
  }
}
```

to schedule the polling.

**Alternatively**, you could stick to implementing all callbacks within a [`unfoldAsyncResource`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stages-overview.html#unfoldasyncresource).

Full implementation of such stage can be found [here](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/c1315a8d1979b4399b62db726c159d64149501f7/file/src/main/java/akka/stream/alpakka/file/javadsl/DirectoryChangesSource.java#L33-L170) (implementation in Java).